# Creating a grouped bar chart

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am very new to R so it would be very helpful is explanations were simplified.

I have been struggling to create a grouped bar chart in R for some time now. I want to have months across my x-axis. I want the bar-chart to be grouped by the two variables as well.

This is the code I have tried so far:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
Months2 <- c('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December')
Qantas <- c(18775,16560,21093,16101,15948,18864,17252,16770,21082,16692,15795,21782)
Ideal <- c(16591,21570,20579,16048,14372,15269,18266,17488,16284,17794,18880,23600)

# reshaping into longdata
InboundQantaslong <- melt(InboundQantas, id=c("Month"))

# make the plot
ggplot(InboundQantaslong) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Months2, y = value, fill = variable), 
           stat="identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.7) +
  scale_fill_manual("Number\n", values = c("red","blue"), 
                    labels = c(" Ideal", " Qantas")) +
  labs(x="\nMonth",y="Number\n") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14)
```

This returns the error

> Insufficient values in manual scale. 15 needed but only 2 provided.

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can correct your code like

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

InboundQantas <- cbind.data.frame(Months2,Qantas,Ideal)

# reshaping into longdata
InboundQantaslong <- melt(InboundQantas, id=c("Months2"))
InboundQantaslong$Months2 <- factor(InboundQantaslong$Months2, levels = c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September","October","November","December"))

ggplot(InboundQantaslong, aes(x = Months2, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.7) +
  scale_fill_manual("Number\n", values = c("red","blue"), 
                    labels = c(" Ideal", " Qantas")) +
  labs(x="\nMonth",y="Number\n") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14)
```

Or using `tidyverse` where `melt` is replaced by `pivot_longer` like

```
InboundQantas$Months2 <- factor(InboundQantas$Months2, levels = c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September","October","November","December"))

InboundQantas %>% pivot_longer(-Months2, names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Months2, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.7) +
  scale_fill_manual("Number\n", values = c("red","blue"), 
                    labels = c(" Ideal", " Qantas")) +
  labs(x="\nMonth",y="Number\n") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked but now i have another issue..the x-axis months are listed alphabetically and not from jan-december & they overlap one another? is there a way to fix this too?

Comment: See my update. If you are using RStudio click on Zoom to overlap of names or click on Export\Save as PDF\Orientation as Landscape\Save.